# HttpWebRequest with impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am working on an application in an environment where users have NTLM, single-sign-on authentication for all applications. Basically, the applications open and they are recognized by gathering information from the user's profile. The application I am working on is an extension to an existing Web Application. This application uses impersonations with an existing service account in Active Directory. Now, inside my application I do a System.Net.HttpWebRequest to a second server that is running a data service. When I place the request I do this:

```
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
            request.Method = "Get";
            using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            { ...
```

As you can see I set the credentials to DefaultNetworkCredentials to make sure that whoever is logged the credentials will be passed in the request. It works well when I tried from the VM hosting my the application. So, if I place the request to my application inside the hosting VM as http://localhost/myapplication it all works fine. However, when I call the same application from outside the VM with the explicit server name as in http://myservername/myapplication, then the secondary server I am requesting the data from rejects the call with a 401 Unauthorized error.

Any ideas? How can I trace what is happening? I tried Fiddler and I do not see anything going on.
Thanks in advance!

UDPATE: I changed the account the application pool runs on to an admin user. I got the same result.

Comment: Is the server set up to do NTLM authentication or Kerberos authentication?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. I have not seen it.

Comment: Well who can say what your problem is?

Comment: I am also having same issue. I set request credentials and also ImpersonationLevel to Impersonation..